# Unable to call view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very new to CodeIgniter. I have a view with the name contact.php in views folder. Now I have a link in index.php and I want to call contact.php view through this link.

My controller Contact.php in the controllers folder :

```
class Contact extends CI_Controller{
function index(){

    $this->load->view('contact');

}
```

}

My link in index.php is

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('contact');?>" class="last">Contact Us</a>
```

my view is not calling it give me page 404 not found..

Comment: Does the URL look correct? If not, what happens when you type in the correct URL?

Comment: Ye what is the url? Have you edited config.php?

Comment: no i have no idea i am very new to codeignator

Comment: @Shomz do you have any explanation what i should do for that

Comment: did you concider this manual page for your issue - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

```
  class ... extends CI_Controller { ... }
```

just see the name of ur class!! Its very important that matches

```
  $this->load->view("myFirstView");
```

(...)

myFirstView.php

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the construct in your controller:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Otherwise you are simply extending the CI_Controller class without inheriting its properties through its construct (hence `parent::__construct();`).